# android crashlytics to detect application suddenly destroyed and disappeared

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

In my application I have 3 Activities,

1-Splash,  2-MainActivity,  3-Audio Activity.

In the Audio Activity, I am using ExoPlayer to play 20 audio files in a loop ( after finishing last file, first file started automatically).

Application is working fine for hours.
Some times and during audio is played (activity in background), the application stops playing without any error message and disappear and I need to reopen the app again. (this happened with two different devices).

below a part from Manifest

```
    <application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"

    >
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1"/>
    <activity android:name="PKG.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyDialogTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name="PKG.PlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyDialogTheme">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="PKG.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard">
    </activity>
```

Crashlytics code added to Main activity ( not splash activity):

```
        final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Crashlytics())
            .debuggable(true)  // Enables Crashlytics debugger
            .build();
    Fabric.with(fabric);
```

My Questions:

- How to use Crashlytics to catch such application stop?
- any other way to catch this crash?

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout this one https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler basically this is probably what Crashalytics uses - there are lots of examples on the net and on this site.

Answer (score 0):

in Application.class

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashExceptionHandler(context));
```

---

```
public class CrashExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

Context mContent;

private CrashExceptionHandler() {

}

public CrashExceptionHandler(Context context) {
    this.mContent = context;
}

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    String errorStr= "";
    for (StackTraceElement obj:e.getStackTrace()) {
        errorStr +=" | "+obj.getFileName()+":"+obj.getClassName()+":"+obj.getMethodName()+":"+obj.getLineNumber();
    }
    // save into file or in log....
}
```

}

Comment: for every crash in app, this will not show the android crash dialog.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this solution and test it. I hope to catch the problem. will let you know

Comment: I implemented it but still no use.`@Override
 public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
  String errorStr =this.mContent.getPackageName();
  for (StackTraceElement obj : e.getStackTrace()) {
   errorStr += " | " + obj.getFileName() + ":" + obj.getClassName() + ":" + obj.getMethodName() + ":" + obj.getLineNumber();

  }
  // save into file or in log....
  Crashlytics.log( " Crashlytics application level: " + errorStr);

 }` may be this is wrong implementation.

Comment: @ kuber: your solution is working for normal crashes. I generated a crash and did the debug and your code is called and executed. however it didn't detect my problem.

Comment: May be you getting some other error, until now i get all crashs report by this which I faces, you should try crashlytic than,

Comment: Crashlytic didn't catch it

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
you have to add crashlytics in gradle like this: implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar')

step 2:  call Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); in your first activity

Note that you have to create account in Fabrics. Also you have add the Fabric plugin to your android studio.
So that crash report would sent to your registered email

Comment: Crashlytics account added. and tested and working, but didn't catch the problem. I am editing my question by adding Crashlytics code